How to update data in subform if the data is in nestded array in zoho crm using deluge
I have the module Quotes, inside the module I have subform quoted_items and inside subform i have three fields quantity, standard_price and I want to fetch the value of quantity and standard_price and multiplication of this two field and update in third field which is extended_standard_price. I have try this code and got success to fetch the data but i am not able to update the record to the third field
 fetch_record = invokeurl
[
url :"https://www.zohoapis.in/crm/v6/Quotes/683769000000338181"
type :GET
connection:"fetch_data_1"
];
 //info fetch_record;
 information = fetch_record.get("data");
 for each  rec in information
 {
 quoted_items = rec.get("Quoted_Items");
 main_map = Map();
 extended_standard_prices = List();
 // Accessing each quoted item
 for each  item in quoted_items
 {
    //maps = Map();
    //maps.put("extended_standard_price",item);
    quantity = item.get("Quantity");
    //info quantity;
    standard_price = item.get("Standard_Price");
    //info standard_price;
    extended_standard_price = quantity * standard_price;
    extended_standard_prices.add(extended_standard_price);
   
  }
 info extended_standard_prices;
 main_map.put("Quoted_Items",extended_standard_prices);
 info main_map;
 update_resp1 = zoho.crm.updateRecord("Quotes",formula_id,main_map);
 info update_resp1;

  }


    fetch_record = invokeurl
    [
    url :"https://www.zohoapis.in/crm/v6/Quotes/683769000000338181"
    type :GET
    connection:"fetch_data_1"
    ];
     //info fetch_record;
     information = fetch_record.get("data");
     for each  rec in information
     {
     quoted_items = rec.getJSON("Quoted_Items");
     main_map = Map();
     extended_standard_prices = List();
     // Accessing each quoted item
     for each  item in quoted_items
     {
        //initialise the map 
        subform = Map();
        subform.put("id",item.get("id"));//passing a subform record "id" against you want to update the third column value 
        quantity = ifnull(item.get("Quantity"),0);
        standard_price = ifnull(item.get("Standard_Price"),0);
        extended_standard_price = quantity * standard_price;
//Add calculated extended standard price to subform
  subform.put("extended_standard_price",extended_standard_price);
  extended_standard_prices.add(subform);
       
      }
     info extended_standard_prices;
     main_map.put("Quoted_Items",extended_standard_prices);
     info main_map;
     update_resp1 = zoho.crm.updateRecord("Quotes",683769000000338181,main_map);
     info update_resp1;
    
      }


Code-only answers are not good answers. Please explain what you've changed and how it addresses the question. (This also applies to all of your current posted answers...)

Thank you for letting me know .I remembering that point in all my future post.
